# Zero (neither positive or negative) attention to challenge proposal in sandbox - what to do?

Tags: discussion, sandbox

A [challenge proposal](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11837/62024) I posted into the sandbox has received zero attention (no votes, no comments).

Should I:

- just post it on the main site and hope for the best?
- do an edit to bump the question up in the "active" sorting?
- consider it failed?
- do something else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Post the link in chat. Usually this encourages more people to look at it.

Comment: Indeed, hopefully this will elicit any negative feedback: if you bring attention to something and people don't down vote, then it can't be too bad. A luke-warm response in the sandbox might just mean that nobody there can imagine themselves solving it; it doesn't mean there is anything wrong with it, and there is a large population that don't frequent the sandbox who may well be interested.